# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while installing idle

Tags: idle

Ii was trying to install IDLE wit this commend:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

but while installation this error show up:

the error's complete shape is this:

```
Setting up idle-python3.5 (3.5.3-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: error processing package idle-python3.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle3:
 idle3 depends on idle-python3.5; however:
  Package idle-python3.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package idle3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 idle-python3.5
 idle3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

tnx for helping me to solve this problem

Comment: Do you have Python *3* installed in your system? Do you have problems installing other things *not* related to Python?

Comment: yes i have installed that.and i've never faced a problem like this before.i edited my Question and added complete shape of error.

Comment: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle3: idle3 depends on idle-python3.5; however: Package idle-python3.5 is not configured yet.` Can you try properly installing `idle-python3.5` by itself *before* trying `idle3`?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: error processing package idle-python3.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle3:
 idle3 depends on idle-python3.5; however:
  Package idle-python3.5 is not configured yet.

Comment: dpkg: error processing package idle3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Comment: i tried sudo apt-get install idle-python3.5 and i faced this things that i entered above

Comment: I tried to see if I could reproduce your problem, but my installation command for `idle3` runs fine w/o issues. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` so that it tries to fix broken packages?

Comment: i tried it now but it gave me the same error again.and  a weird thing happened on my laptop.i woke up this morning and then i saw idle3 has been installed on my laptop :| i think there are ghosts in my laptop :)))))

Comment: So, I'm assuming you no longer have a problem?..

Comment: Yes the problem solved.thank you alot for helping me.